# RXJS loop through items and return an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

My service called "**getList**" returns a list of items.
I want to loop through the list of items and format the date.
Then return the formatted array.

My current attempt doesnt return the items in the array because I use flatMap in order to loop the items in map.

I'm using angular6 and rxjs.

**My attempt:**

```
this.list$ = this.service.getList()
      .pipe(
        flatMap(response => response.items),
        map(item => {
          item.date = moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
          return item;
        })
      );
```

Comment: u can format the date using pipe in template itself

Comment: @mohammedsameen can you show me an example?

Comment: something like: {{list$ | async | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: worked thank you. would be nice to no how to do it using RXJS though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply add `toArray()` at the end of your pipe

```
this.list$ = this.service.getList()
.pipe(
    mergeMap(response => response.items),
    map(item => {
        item.date = moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
        return item;
    }),
    toArray()
)
```

What is probably better though is to restructure a bit your code, use the Observable `map` operator instead of `flatMap` (a.k.a. `mergeMap`) and inside it use the Array `map` method to do the formatting. In other words something like

```
pipe(
    map(response => response.items.map(item => {
        item.date = moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
        return item;
    }))
)
```

The second approach avoids the unfolding of the Array (which in the first solution you do using `flatMap`) and the subsequent recreation of the Array, or at least confines this logic into the `map` method of Array

Answer (score 0):

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormat implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
        if (value) {
            var date = value instanceof Date ? value : new Date(value);
            return DateFormatter.format(date, 'pt', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        }
    }
}
```

Use the above pipe(custome pipe) in your template

```
{{ date | dateFormat}}
```

Comment: don't want a custom pipe solution. They are very slow as well

Answer (score 0):

```
const formatItem = item => {
  item.date = moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
  return item;
};

this.list$ = this.service.getList()
  .pipe(
    flatMap(response => from(response.items.map(formatItem))), // returns Observable<items> from array of items
    // flatMap merges back the observables into one
    toArray()
  );
```